# How to let the frontend know when a background job is done?

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis, background-process, worker

In Heroku long requests can cause H12 timeout errors.

> The request must then be processed...by your application...within 30 seconds to
> avoid the timeout.

[src](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout)

Heroku suggests ***moving long tasks to background jobs.***

> Sending an email...Accessing a remote API...
> Web scraping / crawling...you should move this heavy lifting into a background job which can run asynchronously from your web request.

[src](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout)

Heroku's docs say requests shouldn't take longer than 500ms to return a response.

> It’s important for a web application to serve end-user requests as
> fast as possible. A good rule of thumb is to avoid web requests which
> run longer than 500ms. If you find that your app has requests that
> take one, two, or more seconds to complete, then you should consider
> using a background job instead.

[src](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-redis-workers)

So if I have a background job, ***how do I tell the frontend when the background job is done and what the job returns?***

On Heroku their example code just returns the background job id. But this won't give the frontend the information it needs.

```js
app.post('/job', async (req, res) => {
  let job = await workQueue.add();
  res.json({ id: job.id });
});
```

For example this method won't tell the frontend when an image is done being uploaded. Or the frontend won't know when a call to an API, like an external exchange rate API, returns a result, like an exchange rate, and what that result is.

Someone [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55454493/how-to-listen-to-the-completed-event-in-bull-queue-just-for-the-current-job) using `job.finished()` but doesn't this get you back where you started? Now your requests are waiting for the queue to finish in order to respond. So your requests are the a same length as when there was no queue and this could lead to timeout errors again.

```
      const result = await job.finished();
      res.send(result);
```

This is example uses Bull, Redis, Node.js.

Comment: Are you allowed to have lasting webSocket connections between client and server?  If so, the server could find out when the background job is done and then send a notification to the relevant client over its webSocket.

Comment: Thanks I'll check that suggestion out. When you say "Are you allowed to have lasting webSocket connections between client and server" what do you mean by this? Why wouldn't this be allowed?

Comment: Only some types of hosting plans allow webSockets because they require a continuous resource allocation on the server-side which affects scaling of shared hosting.  That's why I ask.

Comment: The frontend should _not_ simply wait for the job to finish, but allow the user to do some other work in the meantime. Much like you can continue to browse a web page while your browser downloads a big file. The `setInterval(updateJobs, 200)` quoted in your answer points in the right direction, although every 200ms may be too frequent for long-running jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone suggested websockets. I didn't find an example of this yet.

> The idea of using a queue for long tasks is that you post the task and
> then return immediately. I guess you are updating the database as last
> step in your job, and only use the completed event for notifying the
> clients. What you need to do in this case is to implement either a
> **websocket or similar realtime communication** and push the notification
> to relevant clients. This can become complicated so you can save some
> time with a solution like https://pusher.com/ or similar...

https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/issues/1901

I also saw a solution in [heroku's full example](https://github.com/heroku-examples/node-workers-example), which I didn't originally see:

web server

```js
// Fetch updates for each job
async function updateJobs() {
  for (let id of Object.keys(jobs)) {
    let res = await fetch(`/job/${id}`);
    let result = await res.json();
    if (!!jobs[id]) {
      jobs[id] = result;
    }
    render();
  }
}
```

frontend

```js
// Fetch updates for each job
async function updateJobs() {
  for (let id of Object.keys(jobs)) {
    let res = await fetch(`/job/${id}`);
    let result = await res.json();
    if (!!jobs[id]) {
      jobs[id] = result;
    }
    render();
  }
}

// Attach click handlers and kick off background processes
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("#add-job").addEventListener("click", addJob);
  document.querySelector("#clear").addEventListener("click", clear);

  setInterval(updateJobs, 200);
};
```